# $a ≡ b \pmod{n_1}$ and $a ≡ b\pmod{n_2}$, then $a ≡ b\pmod{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Verify that if $a \equiv b\pmod{n_1}$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{n_2}$, then $a \equiv b\pmod{n}$, where the integer $n = \mathrm{lcm}(n_1 , n_2)$. Hence, whenever $n_1$ and $n_2$ are relatively prime, $a \equiv b\pmod{n_1n_2}$.

So I know that if $a \equiv b\pmod{n_1}$ then $n_1 \mid a - b$ and if $a \equiv b\pmod{n_2}$ then $n_2 \mid a - b$, and so $n_1n_2\mid (a - b)(a - b)$, but how do I show that $n\mid a-b$ and make the correlation between $n$ and $n_1n_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One solution:** [Use this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Otherwise, what you need to prove is that
$$
n_1 \mid d \text{ and } n_2 \mid d \implies \text{lcm}(n_1,n_2)\mid d
$$
How you would go about doing this depends on how you define (i.e. how your textbook defines) $\text{lcm}(n_1,n_2)$

Answer (score 0):

Let, $gcd(u,v)=d$ and $u|m$  and $v|m$

Write $ux+vy=d$, $m=uu'$, $m=vv'$.

Now, $md = m(ux+vy) = mux+mvy = vv'ux+uu'vy = uv(v'x+u'y)$

So we have, $uv|md$

$i.e.$ $(uv/d)|m$

since, $gcd(u,v)lcm(u,v)=uv$

Therefore we have ,

$lcm(u,v)|m$

Here $n_1=u$, $n_2=v$ and $m=(a-b)$

So form the above result we have

$lcm(n_1,n_2)|(a-b)$

In other words,
$a \equiv b\pmod{lcm(n_1,n_2})$

Answer (score -3):

For two numbers $a$ and $b$, $\gcd(a,b) \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=a\cdot b$
let $\gcd(a,b)=d$ therefore,
$dn=n_1n_2$
so $n$ divides $n_1n_2 [eq1]$
as you have mentioned in your query,
$n_1n_2$ divides $(a-b)(a-b) [eq2]$.
By $eq1$ and $eq2$ ,$n$ divides $(a-b)$
$a\equiv b\pmod n [eq 3]$
hence proved

as for the second part,
if $gcd=1$ ,then $n_1n_2=n$
we can replace $n$ by $n_1n_2$ in the congruence $eq3$.
hence proved.